# Loading JSON data into alertdialog into spinner

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to retrieve Json data into a spinner that's in an alertdialog  , it only loads if the spinner in the same activity but if it's in an alertDialog it gives me this Error :

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference

```
package exir.exir;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

 import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
   import android.widget.Spinner;
   import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
   import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
   import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
   import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

   import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import exir.exir.Helpers.FormAdapter;
    import exir.exir.Helpers.PatientsAdapter;
    import exir.exir.Helpers.PricrMAdapter;
    import exir.exir.Helpers.RequestHandler;
   import exir.exir.Helpers.SharedPrefManager;
     import exir.exir.Rertofit.MyLabAPI;
    import exir.exir.Utils.Constants;
    import exir.exir.model.Form;
    import exir.exir.model.PMenus;
     import exir.exir.model.PriceM;
    import exir.exir.model.RPatient;
     import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
     import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable;
     import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
     import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

   import static android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item;

  public class AddPatient extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText patientname, gender , age , agetype , tel ,
        phone ,  total , notes  , testno , testprice , testnotes , testname1 , testno1 , testprice1 , testnotes1  ;
private Button  add ;




private String URLstring = "https://demonuts.com/Demonuts/JsonTest/Tennis/json_parsing.php";




String labId , labpriceMenuNO ;


private static ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private ArrayList<PMenus> goodModelArrayList;
private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

private Spinner PmSpinner;


MyLabAPI myLabAPI ;
CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

List<PriceM> pricemenilist;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

ListView FormList ;
EditText editThen , edtSdt;
Button btn_sua , btn_xoa , btn_then ;
ArrayList<Form> formArrayList ;
FormAdapter formAdapter;
FloatingActionButton newTest ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_patient);



    testno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.testno);
    testprice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.testprice);
    testnotes = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.testnotes);


    newTest = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id. 
     newTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showNewTestDialog();
        }
    });







    myLabAPI = Constants.getAPI();




    add =(Button)findViewById(R.id.addPatient);








}


private void showNewTestDialog() {



    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new 
    AlertDialog.Builder(AddPatient.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Add New Test ");
    alertDialog.setMessage("PLease fill the info  ");

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View formLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newtest_layout, null);

    editThen = formLayout.findViewById(R.id.FName);
    edtSdt = formLayout.findViewById(R.id.FPrice);

    goodModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    PmSpinner  = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.testname);

    PmSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    PmSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
     AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
          position, long id) {

            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() ;
            String testum = goodModelArrayList.get(position).getCity() ;
            String price = goodModelArrayList.get(position).getCountry() ;



            testnotes.setText(item);
            testno.setText(testum);
            testprice.setText(price);


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    retrieveJSON();

    alertDialog.setView(formLayout);
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);


    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new 
      DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            dialogInterface.dismiss();


        //some code

        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new 
       DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();




}














private void retrieveJSON() {


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URLstring,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d("strrrrr", ">>" + response);

                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                         goodModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                            JSONArray dataArray  = obj.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {



                                PMenus playerModel = new PMenus();

                                JSONObject dataobj = 
                       dataArray.getJSONObject(i);




                           playerModel.setName(dataobj.getString("name"));


                    playerModel.setCountry(dataobj.getString("country"));

                        playerModel.setCity(dataobj.getString("city"));

                       playerModel.setImgURL(dataobj.getString("imgURL"));



                                goodModelArrayList.add(playerModel);



                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < goodModelArrayList.size(); 
                                 i++){

                  names.add(goodModelArrayList.get(i).getName().toString());
                            }

                            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new 
          ArrayAdapter<String>(AddPatient.this, simple_spinner_item, names);

 spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
                            PmSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
  error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    // request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


}
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your question. But you have a real import madness right there. Try using a star `*` like `import com.android.volley.*` instead of adding each individual class.

Comment: oh thanks , i will , but this is just a part of my code so those imports were sat for the rest of it

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
JSONObject c = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.1.104/OnlineTicketBooking/book_now1.php?movieid='72'");

try {
    JSONArray jarray = c.getJSONArray("offer_detail");
    ArrayList<String> xyz= new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
    JSONArray timeArray = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("showtime");
    for(int j = 0; j < timeArray .length(); j++){
        xyz.add(timeArray .getString(j));
        Log.d("get value",timeArray .getString(j));`enter code here`
    } 
}
```